# How to style MVC3/ASP.net DropDownList?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, css

How can I style a mvc3/asp.net DropDownList in css like I can with a text box:

--Site.css - Style for text box--

```
input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #93A9C8;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #444;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
```

}

MVC3 Display:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"],
select {
    border: 1px solid #93A9C8;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #444;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
```

alternatively, you can add a style to the dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ID, Model.MyList, new { @class="selectStyle" })
```

so you could do the following in the css:

```
.selectStyle { /* whatever */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add select to your CSS.

Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6aBW/).

Answer (score 1):

The drop down list renders to a "select" element, not an "input" element, so your CSS would have to include "select" as well.

Know also that selects are sometimes notoriously difficult to style.  Much of their design is governed by the platform, not the CSS on the page.  There are a number of ways around this, the most elegant of which are usually simple [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/select-box).  The one called "Chosen" is particularly good, in my opinion.  But be aware that obscuring the standard select element functionality can sometimes cause usability issues on mobile devices and other touch interfaces.  So test your target platforms accordingly.